# UCT algorithm on embedded systems

Tags: algorithm, embedded, arduino, artificial-intelligence

In connection with one of my projects, I have to design an artificial intelligence for Go game on an embedded system. I've chosen to use [UCT](http://senseis.xmp.net/?UCT) algorithm, but I fear I have too few memory.

Actually I am using [Arduino Mega 2560](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/arduinoBoardMega2560) microcontroller, which has an SRAM of 8 KB size (and a 16 MHz clock speed). How to design the tree efficiently in order to fit in memory?

Comment: From your provided UTC link, it was noted that building a tree in memory will quickly consume ram and that an alternative is to use transposition tables (Unfortunately it doesn't get into details of how to do this.)  Other than that I don't have any ideas; you've selected an algorithm that needs a lot of ram, but a system that has little...

Comment: Can't you add some external memory ICs?

Comment: This size of your tree depends on the size of your board.  19x19 is huge.  Do you have to use the Chinese rules?  Could you not do GoMoku (Japanese) or Omok (Korean) which will work on an 8x8 board.

Comment: @Ross: I'll inquire about this utilisation of transposition tables. Thanks.

Comment: @ziggystar: Well I think I can. However I don't know so much about these circuits. What would you recommend?

Comment: @cup: (I've forgotten these details on the OP.) Actually I work on 9x9 board.

Comment: Have a look at this: http://ruggedcircuits.com/html/megaram.html; I would even consider adding more RAM, but at some point your code will have to handle RAM pages.